# Delete a list of items in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to clear all items from an Entity Framework collection, in this case, remove all food from a plate. Any ideas how I can resolve the following - The code below generates the error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An entity object cannot be referenced by
>   multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

```
Plate selPlate = (Plate)Session["selPlate"];

foreach (FoodForPlate f in selPlate.FoodForPlates)
{
    context.Entry(f).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
}

context.SaveChanges();

bindstats();

UpdatePanel1.Update();
```

Comment: You're having this issue because Session["selPlate"] is still being tracked by another instance of your DbContext, most likely the one you used to get the data in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, it's clear from the second error. And yes, as Brian said, you are probably already tracking the same entity in another instance of DbContext. Make you dispose the context before using another one.

Comment: You don't need to dispose of the other context first. You just need to detach the entity from it, and attach to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework keeps track of your loaded items so it can detect changes and you have some of those objects loaded already. Try:

```
dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

You can also try disabling object tracking but that depends on your application requirements.